# MySQL 5.6 CAST String to Int returns Error 1064

Tags: mysql, casting, syntax-error

Working with a book to teach me SQL, I stumbled over an exercise that returns me an Error 1064 Code even though I used the recommended solution to the exercise.

**The exercise:** 
Cast the string '5' as INTEGER and add it to the numeric value 20. 
Display the result.

**Code is:**

```
SELECT CAST('5' AS INTEGER) + 20 AS summe;
```

**Error code:**
"Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTEGER) + 20 AS summe' at line 1"

**Result should be:** 25

I was able to find a workaround by casting the string to a decimal/numeric first. But in the process of learning I'm eager to understand my own (or the book's) mistakes to improve.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Works fine for me in 5.7

Comment: @P.Salmon up to 5.7 you have to use `SIGNED` or `UNSIGNED` (with `INTEGER` as an optional suffix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use signed:

```
SELECT CAST('5' AS SIGNED integer) + 20 AS summe
```